# Como verificar se o e-mail já está cadastrado no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

O Controller está sempre retornando a mensagem de erro, quando o e-mail está ou não cadastrado no banco de dados.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha")] Pessoas pessoas)
{
    if (pessoas != null)
    {
        var verificaemail = db.Pessoas.Where(w => w.Email == "Email").FirstOrDefault();
        if (verificaemail != null)
        {                                        
            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoas);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-mail já cadastrado");
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(pessoas);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está comparando se o e-mail é igual a string "Email" enquanto na verdade veria comparer se é o que contem no model pessoa desta forma `pessoas.Email`

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha")] Pessoas pessoas)
{
    if (pessoas != null)
    {
        var verificaemail = db.Pessoas.Where(w => w.Email == pessoas.Email).FirstOrDefault();
        if (verificaemail != null)
        {                                        
            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoas);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-mail já cadastrado");
            return View(pessoas);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Detalhe, se 'pessoas' estiver 'null' é para retornar 'View(pessoas)'?

Creio que isso deveria estar no 'else' interno.

Comment: Verdade, bem denotado alterei a resposta

Comment: Agora está funcionando, mas com um porém, está ao contrario, quando era para dar o erro ele cadastra, e quando era para cadastrar está dando erro. Então acho que minha lógica está errada.

Answer (score 4):

Isso?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha")] Pessoa pessoa) {
    if (pessoa != null) {
        if (db.Pessoas.Where(w => w.Email == pessoa.Email).FirstOrDefault() != null) {                                        
            db.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "E-mail já cadastrado");
            return View();
        }
    } else return View(pessoa);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/HasMail.cs).

Comment: Está funcionando, mas com um porém, está ao contrario, quando era para dar o erro ele cadastra, e quando era para cadastrar está dando erro. Acho que minha lógica estava errada.

Comment: Eu fiz baseado no que você postou e o que puder inferir, se der mais alguma informação posso tentar melhorar

Comment: Se eu alterar o if (pessoa != null) para (pessoa == null) faz mas sentido a lógica do código?

Comment: Acho que não, mas precisaria ver mais contexto.